# Simple PL/SQL Procedure. Getting PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

Trying to create a very simple authentication procedure for use in Oracle APEX. My procedure is below

```
create or replace function pmats_authenticate(uname in varchar2, pass in varchar2)
return boolean
as
begin
   declare
   afound number:=0;
   begin
     select 1 from dual into afound;
     if afound = 1 then
        return true;
     else
        return false;
     end if;
   end;
end pmats_authenticate;
```

And I get the old PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored thing on the select. I got the select down to the simplest thing I could think of 'select 1 from dual'. I'm scratching my head on this one I'm afraid.

Comment: Have you had a look at the PL/SQL reference guide?  You have made a fairly obvious syntax error.  [Can you spot it?](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/fundamentals.htm#LNPLS222)

Comment: Aha! Thank you.. format is create or replace function... as [variable specs] begin [procedure body] end;

Answer (score 3):

The INTO clause goes before the FROM clause, so your SELECT statement should read

```
SELECT 1 INTO afound FROM DUAL
```

For reference the general structure of a `SELECT` is

```
WITH ...common table expressions...
SELECT ...fields...
INTO ...bind variables...
FROM ...tables...
INNER JOIN ...other tables... ON ...conditions...
LEFT|RIGHT|FULL OUTER JOIN ...other tables... ON ...conditions...
WHERE ...conditions...
GROUP BY ...fields...
HAVING ...conditions...
```

Share and enjoy.

Comment: Thanks Bob. I figured that one out. Tried calling my procedure and got an error but that's because SQL doesn't recognise the Boolean data type (maybe it's about time Oracle got round to adding that functionality to SQL ;))

Comment: My usual work-around for that is to return `'Y'` or `'N'` instead of a `BOOLEAN`. Share and enjoy.